# MariaDB server running 10 x faster than anything we can reproduce. Ideas why?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, memory-management, mariadb

we've got a site on cheap, shared hosting.

They've got a MariaDB server, which I presume is shared by many customers. We run some pretty chunky queries on this and get fast responses. We want to move the hosting elsewhere, but we simply can't get a database running anywhere near as fast.

We've tried on a new VPS server, with SSD, 12 cores and 16 gigs ram. Queries are taking 10 times longer than the shared hosting's db.
(In fact, increasing number of cores made little difference). We tried MySQL and MariaDB + our hosts also setup lightspeed, memcache and Redis, but they didn't help.

For a specific query I've been testing with, the shared server takes approx 0.7 seconds to run, the new server takes about 8 seconds.

We've checked that the indexes are in place (the EXPLAIN query looks the same on both), and we're confident that the whole query isn't cached because minor changes to the query don't effect speed. The output is tiny, so it's the processing that's slower.

The slow queries are long and wide ranging, but effectively it's when it's inefficiently trying to match rows where an ID is saved as a varchar. eg.

```
SELECT post.ID
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN meta
ON post.ID = meta.postID
AND meta.key = "ABC"
WHERE post.type = "XYZ"
AND meta.value = "123456";
```

An EXPLAIN on a slow query reveals:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, _booking_all_day, ref, "post_id,meta_key", meta_key, 576, const, 71474, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
....
```

I've pasted the SHOW VARIABLES for each server here:
https://pastebin.com/iW6WL3zC - fast, shared server.
https://pastebin.com/kJGKHyqs - new, slower server.

I have a decent amount of experience with MySQL, but I'm no db engineer! This is my first time with a MariaDB so I don't know if there are important optimisations that I'm unaware of.

One obvious answer is re-write the bad SQL code. We will do, but we will need to move the hosting before we have time to do that. This question is just on why the same query could be so different / any recommendations for trying to get the new server running as fast (or even faster)! Thanks.

Comment: Move the meta.value = "123456" condition to the ON clause to get true left join result. As it is now you get regular inner join result.

Comment: And probably you should use single quotes for string literals, and no quotes for numeric literals (even in mysql?)

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess that there is a collation issue that prevents the use of indexes -- that is, the default collation used for the queries differs from the collations that exist on the columns with indexes.

Comment: @jarlh thanks. The original query that I simplified for the example had two joins, and in the WHERE clauses it had meta1 OR meta2. This might be something that makes it very inefficient, but I don't know why that would make a difference between one server and the other?

Comment: @joop thanks, I think it's right to use the quotes here because the field it's matching is a varchar. Aka whether I like it or not, it's stored in meta.value as "123456".

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks! Both have the same collation: latin1 / latin1_swedish_ci. (Not originally set by me). Does this rule out your suggestion, or is there more to it?

Comment: @JamieG . . . Is the collation the same on the server, database, and column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff... good question - I hadn't realised they could be different, but they were. I haven't ascertained what the server is yet, but the column was utf-8. I changed the database and column to match, but it didn't actual make any speed differences. NB: These were different on the fast server too.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` as well.

Comment: @joop - Single/double quotes -- either is fine in MySQL.  Quoting integer literals in MySQL has no impact.

Comment: @JamieG - To verify the collations, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: @JamieG - No fair.  That `OR` can make a _huge_ difference in the ability to Optimize the query.  Is your simplified query also slower on the newer machine?

Comment: Database and Table charset/collation are _defaults_; hence irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..3zC Old, fast:  MariaDB 10.1.27 buffer_pool=18G
..yqs New, slow:  MariaDB 10.1.37 buffer_pool=128M

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is very important to performance.  Your 10x clue is what I often see as the difference between I/O-bound and in-cache.

How much RAM in each machine?  The buffer_pool should be about 70% of *available* RAM.

Meanwhile, do they have the same version of WP?

A tips on improving WP's postmeta performance:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta
The recommended index change *may* actually speed up *that* query in the slower machine enough to match the faster machine.

Comment: Thanks Rick. The buffer pool made a huge difference. We managed to get the new server down to about 1.2 seconds where the old one is 0.7 seconds. So it's not as fast, but we don't have 18 gigs space for a DB so perhaps not too surprising!

We've then re-indexed our meta table as suggested in that article and it's transformed. Down to 0.1 seconds on our server. Phew. Many, many thanks.

Comment: @JamieG - Glad to hear your results.  As a Rule Of Thumb -- Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of available RAM.  (Not knowing the size of the old server, I did not question the 18G.  That would be OK for 24GB of RAM, but _not_ for 16GB.)

Comment: so if you have less than 24 GB of memory ...
And even less than 16G ...

The question remains the following ...

This is useful in the case of a memory of 2 GB / 4 GB up to 8 GB. with 2 processor cores. In this case, a VPS.

Comment: @PauloBoaventura - Start a new Question with more details.  How much in your dataset?  Are any queries noticeably slow?